# Loading XML or XHTML content with html encoded or escaped characters

Tags: c#, .net, xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I'm developing a class for a content management system. The input content is supplied in XHTML format. And it can contain valid escaped characters like `&#163;` See the example below.

```
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head xmlns="">
    <meta name="Attr_DocumentTitle" content="Hello World Books" />
   </head>
  <body>

 <div>British Pound   &#163;</div>

 <div>Registered sign &#174;</div>

 <div>Copyright sign &#169; </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

My objective is to write a method that loads this to an XML .Net object do some processing and save to database. I want to maintain the escaped characters as they are. And here is my method:

```
public static XmlDocument LoadXmlFromString(string xhtmlContent)
{
    byte[] xhtmlByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xhtmlContent);
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(xhtmlByte);
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
    //Upon loading XML, prevent DTD download, which would be blocked by our 
    //firewall and generate "503 Server Unavailable" error.
    settings.XmlResolver = null;
    settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(mStream, settings);
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xhtmlContent);
    return xmlDoc; //Value of xmlDoc.InnerXml contains £ ® © in place 
                    // of &#163; &#174; and &#169;
}
```

This method however converts the escaped characters to their character equivalents. How can I avoid this and keep the escaped characters.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Do you want XML or text?

Comment: To render it in a browser. With special characters it throws error because it will not be a valid xml.

Comment: So I want xml and I want the value of xmlDoc.InnerXml to have escaped characters. I don't understand why it replaces the escaped characters upon loading, it makes the xml invalid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.NET XmlDocument LoadXML and Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152900/net-xmldocument-loadxml-and-entities). Short answer: that's by design and shouldn't bother you. What really matters is the way you output the markup to the browser.

Comment: @ReggaeMan — if it is throwing errors, then you have a character encoding problem. Deal with that problem instead of trying to work around it.

Comment: I believe its critical to sanitize both the data going and also going out. See here: http://markupsanitizer.codeplex.com/ for some more ideas...

Comment: ReggeaMan, XML and XHTML build on and support Unicode so there is no need to escape non-ASCII characters in XHTML to have well-formed XHTML and to have it render properly in browsers. Thus I think if you have problems with getting characters like `£` properly rendered then that is simply a problem of letting the browser know the encoding of the document you send so make sure you set the charset parameter of the Content-Type HTTP header.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Thanks for the link it helped a lot. And I stopped trying to retain the escaped characters. @Martin Honnen I tried sending files with special characters like £ and it works if I save the file as UTF-8 encoded using Notepad++. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this:
[why does xmltextreader convert html encoded utf8 characters to utf8 string automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308230/why-does-xmltextreader-convert-html-encoded-utf8-characters-to-utf8-string-automa)

Comment: The following blog by Joel Spolsky helped as well. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html