# Serializing options for non-breaking spaces

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I have an XML document, that I want to load manipulate and then save back to disk. One of the elements has text that contains a non-breaking space `&#160;` in it. When I serialize the document back it comes out as a non-breaking space but not the code point like it was in the original. This problem also effects other code points like `&amp;` and `&quot;`, but not `&lt;` and `&gt;` since the later would not be legal in elements. You don't even need to manipulate the document to cause it to replace the characters.

Is there any way to get it to serialize back as the code point? 
Document example

```
<Node>
<InnerNode>Some&#160;Text</InnerNode>
</Node>
```

Code example

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument {PreserveWhitespace = true};
doc.Load(fileStream.BaseStream);
doc.Save(path);
```

Comment: Duplicate of [.NET XmlDocument LoadXML and Entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152900)? Basically, it shouldn't matter if the non-breaking space is encoded directly (if the output character set supports it) or if it uses an entity such as `&#160;` -- or `&#xA0;` or `&#xa0;` or possibly `&nbsp;` which all means the same. Entities are only _required_ if the output character set can't represent the character otherwise.

Comment: @Burkart I know it is not required. But when a person views the XML document the difference between it being an entity or not an entity is significant for the space for the purpose I am using it for. Given the number of options available for serialization I assumed this was in there somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your goal can be achieved by using a [decorated `XmlWriter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364889/need-to-overwrite-xmlwriters-method) object. The code below replaces non-breaking spaces with the XML entity `&#160;` in the `WriteString` method.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader fileStream = new StreamReader("input.xml");
            string path = "output.xml";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument { PreserveWhitespace = true };
            doc.Load(fileStream.BaseStream);

            // Do some processing...

            MyXmlWriter writer = new MyXmlWriter(XmlWriter.Create(path));
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
    }

    public class MyXmlWriter : XmlWriter
    {
        private readonly XmlWriter writer;

        public MyXmlWriter(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            if (writer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("writer");
            this.writer = writer;
        }

        // Output non-breaking space as character entity
        public override void WriteString(string text)
        {
            string[] parts = text.Split((char)160);
            for (int i = 0; i < parts.Count(); i++)
            {
                this.writer.WriteString(parts[i]);
                if (i + 1 < parts.Count())
                    this.writer.WriteRaw("&#160;");
            }
        }

        // The rest of the XmlWriter methods implemented using Decorator Pattern
        public override void Close()
        {
            this.writer.Close();
        }

        public override string LookupPrefix(string ns)
        {
            return this.writer.LookupPrefix(ns);
        }

        public override void Flush()
        {
            this.writer.Flush();
        }

        public override WriteState WriteState
        {
            get { return this.writer.WriteState; }
        }

        public override void WriteBase64(byte[] buffer, int index, int count)
        {
            this.writer.WriteBase64(buffer, index, count);
        }

        public override void WriteRaw(string data)
        {
            this.writer.WriteRaw(data);
        }

        public override void WriteRaw(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
        {
            this.writer.WriteRaw(buffer, index, count);
        }

        public override void WriteChars(char[] buffer, int index, int count)
        {
            this.writer.WriteChars(buffer, index, count);
        }

        public override void WriteSurrogateCharEntity(char lowChar, char highChar)
        {
            this.writer.WriteSurrogateCharEntity(lowChar, highChar);
        }

        public override void WriteWhitespace(string ws)
        {
            this.writer.WriteWhitespace(ws);
        }

        public override void WriteCharEntity(char ch)
        {
            this.writer.WriteCharEntity(ch);
        }

        public override void WriteEntityRef(string name)
        {
            this.writer.WriteEntityRef(name);
        }

        public override void WriteProcessingInstruction(string name, string text)
        {
            this.writer.WriteProcessingInstruction(name, text);
        }

        public override void WriteComment(string text)
        {
            this.writer.WriteComment(text);
        }

        public override void WriteCData(string text)
        {
            this.writer.WriteCData(text);
        }

        public override void WriteEndAttribute()
        {
            this.writer.WriteEndAttribute();
        }

        public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
        {
            this.writer.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
        }

        public override void WriteFullEndElement()
        {
            this.writer.WriteFullEndElement();
        }

        public override void WriteStartElement(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
        {
            this.writer.WriteStartElement(prefix, localName, ns);
        }

        public override void WriteEndElement()
        {
            this.writer.WriteEndElement();
        }

        public override void WriteDocType(string name, string pubid, string sysid, string subset)
        {
            this.writer.WriteDocType(name, pubid, sysid, subset);
        }

        public override void WriteEndDocument()
        {
            this.writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }

        public override void WriteStartDocument(bool standalone)
        {
            this.writer.WriteStartDocument(standalone);
        }

        public override void WriteStartDocument()
        {
            this.writer.WriteStartDocument();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So obvious now that it's there in front me. Thanks!